# logstash 7.10.1 : Java issue

Tags: java, logstash

After an upgrade to 7.10.1 on logstash I get

```html
/etc/logstash$ /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f .
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCTimeStamps'
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCTimeStamps'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

And unable to start it. Thanks for your help

Comment: did you check do you have Java 8 sdk and JAVA_HOME set

Comment: Problem is now logstsh is using an embedded jdk. I'm trying to comment all cc stuff and if OK I'll update this thread